# How do I make intellisense work for referenced projects within a solution in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

I have a C# solution consisting of 12 projects.  One project (called myControls) is where I'm creating custom Silverlight controls.  I consume some of the controls under myControls in another project called (Viewer).  I have verified that my namespaces and class names are correct under both projects.

But then I try to reference two brand new controls in Viewer from myControls, Intellisense doesn't seem to recognize my brand new controls although it sees the other ones.  I have verified that my namespaces are correct in Viewer, I have verified that my references to myControls resides in the References folder.  Is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a brand new project or new controls it doesn't always build references--for me at least--until the project has been built for the first time and compiles. Also, if they have a backing class, make sure that your namespaces between the linked classes for your control are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access Modifier of the control class: public, private, internal, etc. Select the one that you think will fit better, use public for instance.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

What type of project is this?  WinForms or WebForms?
But you should see your controls in the toolbox as well.

Also, why so many projects?  One side effect of this approach is that your build will be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the project with the controls and select Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are probably private, or they don't have a public default constructor.